# Automate JSON substrings with semi-random data to KQL?

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, grafana, kql

So currently I have the following simple code to just build out a table for myself and look at data

```
azure_devops_work_item_events_CL
| summarize any(WorkItemType_s, TeamProject_s, Title_s, 
      AssignedTo_s, State_s, Reason_s) by WorkItemId_d, Relations_s
| order by WorkItemId_d desc
```

My problem is the Relations_s data is pulling a super long string that's different in length pretty much every instance although the format is the same for each one ex:

| Relations_s |
| --- |
| [ { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/197138", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Parent" } } ] |
| [ { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/d88804f3-b064-4489-9705/_apis/wit/workItems/234449", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Parent" } } ] |
| [ { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/247970", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/242838", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/242835", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/246163", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/234839", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/229566", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/228347", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/240648", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/234833", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/240647", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/242837", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/234803", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/234801", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/246352", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/242839", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/234834", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/234838", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/242836", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/218335", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Parent" } }, { "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward", "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/234832", "attributes": { "isLocked": false, "name": "Child" } } ] |

This is a small sample of what my table looks like when I query it. I'm completely lost on how I can parse the table in such a way that I'm able to automate pulling the number at the end of every link and the name portion at the end of each string. Especially when some parts of the table have 40 strings in 1. Note all the data is in the form of a JSON if that impacts this at all. The end result needs to look something like this

| Child | Parent |
| --- | --- |
| 240241 | 240541 |

Or this

| Item | Link |
| --- | --- |
| 240241 | Child |
| 240541 | Parent |

Apologies for the formatting I can't get the massive data set to properly format into a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to its name `Relations_s` is probably a string, therefore needs conversion to JSON (by using `todynamic()`).

###### Option 1

```
azure_devops_work_item_events_CL
|   mv-apply todynamic(Relations_s) on
    (
            parse       Relations_s.url with * "/" Item:long
        |   project     Item
                       ,Link = Relations_s.attributes.name
        |   summarize   Parent   = take_anyif   (Item ,Link == "Parent")
                       ,Children = make_list_if (Item ,Link == "Child")
    )
```

| Parent | Children |
| --- | --- |
| 197138 | [] |
| 234449 | [] |
| 218335 | [247970,242838,242835,246163,234839,229566,228347,240648,234833,240647,242837,234803,234801,246352,242839,234834,234838,242836,234832] |

###### Option 2

```
azure_devops_work_item_events_CL
|   mv-apply todynamic(Relations_s) on
    (
            parse       Relations_s.url with * "/" Item:long
        |   project     Item
                       ,Link = Relations_s.attributes.name
        |   summarize   Parent   = take_anyif   (Item ,Link == "Parent")
                       ,Children = make_list_if (Item ,Link == "Child")
        |   mv-expand   Children = iff(array_length(Children) == 0, dynamic(null), Children) to typeof(long)
    )
```

| Parent | Children |
| --- | --- |
| 197138 |  |
| 234449 |  |
| 218335 | 247970 |
| 218335 | 242838 |
| 218335 | 242835 |
| 218335 | 246163 |
| 218335 | 234839 |
| 218335 | 229566 |
| 218335 | 228347 |
| 218335 | 240648 |
| 218335 | 234833 |
| 218335 | 240647 |
| 218335 | 242837 |
| 218335 | 234803 |
| 218335 | 234801 |
| 218335 | 246352 |
| 218335 | 242839 |
| 218335 | 234834 |
| 218335 | 234838 |
| 218335 | 242836 |
| 218335 | 234832 |

Comment: Oh my goodness it worked and I am in awe. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your description correctly, you could try the following, using the `mv-apply` and `parse` operators:

```
datatable(d:dynamic)
[
    dynamic([
    {
        "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/197138",
        "attributes": {
            "isLocked": false,
            "name": "Parent"
        }
    }
]), dynamic([
    {
        "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/d88804f3-b064-4489-9705/_apis/wit/workItems/234449",
        "attributes": {
            "isLocked": false,
            "name": "Parent"
        }
    }
]), dynamic([
    {
        "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/247970",
        "attributes": {
            "isLocked": false,
            "name": "Child"
        }
    },
    {
        "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/242838",
        "attributes": {
            "isLocked": false,
            "name": "Child"
        }
    },
    {
        "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/a69ffa35-e99f-42ea-a254/_apis/wit/workItems/242835",
        "attributes": {
            "isLocked": false,
            "name": "Child"
        }
    }
]),
]
| mv-apply d on (
    parse d with * "/workItems/" item:long *
    | extend link = tostring(d.attributes.name)
)
| project item, link
```

| item | link |
| --- | --- |
| 197138 | Parent |
| 234449 | Parent |
| 247970 | Child |
| 242838 | Child |
| 242835 | Child |

Comment: Is it not possible in KQL for the datatable to automatically be built out by the data log im using so that the data doesnt have to be manually input?

Comment: the example in my answer uses an inline `datatable` as I and other readers of this tread don't have access to your cluster/data set. the exact same logic (everything 
after `datatable(...)[...] |` should work on the original data set, for anyone who has access to it. based on your original question, I'm guessing in your case it would be `azure_devops_work_item_events_CL | project-rename d = Relations_s | mv-apply d ...`

Comment: I think moreso my question would be can I use the JSON from the data set im using and import/use that as the `datatable` instead of having to build out a `datatable` ? Apologies if it seems like I'm asking dumb questions I'm brand new to KQL

Comment: you don't need to use a `datatable` if your data is already ingested into a table (e.g. the one named `azure_devops_work_item_events_CL` in your case). Just query your existing table, where the data already exists in a dynamic column (named `Relations_s` in your case)